# Python - Strange "Unexpected Indent" Error

Tags: python-2.7

**BEFORE READING MY QUESTION I WANT TO SAY THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO WILL AT LEAST TRY TO HELP ME**

Hey guys! Few weeks ago I decided to learn scripting in Python 2. I used learnpythonthehardway book. Now I tried to make little game but when I launched my game it typed really strange "Unexpected Indent" Error. I am sure that there is nothing wrong with my script... here it is:

```
import random
```

print "Airchiet sirtule:"
print "Sheudzlebeli [1,250]"

sirtule = raw_input("< ")

elif sirtule == "Sheudzlebeli":
    rand4 = random.randint(1,250)

```
print "Gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi [1,250]"
print "Sirtule - Sheudzlebeli."
print "Mcdelobebis raodenoba - 7"

tryh1 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh1) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh1) < int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh1) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."

tryh2 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh2) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh2) < int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh2) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh3 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh3) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh3) < int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh3) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh4 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh4) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh4) < int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh4) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh5 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh5) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh5) < int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh5) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh6 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh6) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh6) > int(rand4)):
        print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
    elif (int(tryh6) == int(rand4)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh7 = raw_input("< ")
    if (int(tryh7) != int(rand4)):
        print "Samwuxarod tqven waaget."
        print "Chafiqrebuli ricxvi iyo -", rand4,
    elif (int(tryh7) == int(rand)):
        print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
```

Error I get : "File 'gc.py', line 234
                if(itn(tryh1) > int(rand4)):
               IndentationError: unexpected indent "

**I WANT TO ALSO SAY SORRY. I'M SORRY FOR THIS VERY STUPID QUESTION, REASON FOR IT IS THAT I AM NEWBIE AT SCRIPTING.**

Comment: Unindent your `if`s and `elif`s so that they are at the same level as the line above them, ie `tryh1 = raw_input("< ")`, and unindent the code inside those blocks by the same amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, Indentation matters and this error is saying something is wrong with your indentation. The if statement doesn't need to be indented in this case. So the correct code would be

```
print "Gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi [1,250]"
print "Sirtule - Sheudzlebeli."
print "Mcdelobebis raodenoba - 7"

tryh1 = raw_input("< ")
if (int(tryh1) > int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh1) < int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh1) == int(rand4)):
    print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."

tryh2 = raw_input("< ")
if (int(tryh2) > int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh2) < int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh2) == int(rand4)):
    print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh3 = raw_input("< ")
if (int(tryh3) > int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh3) < int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh3) == int(rand4)):
    print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh4 = raw_input("< ")
if (int(tryh4) > int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh4) < int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh4) == int(rand4)):
    print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
tryh5 = raw_input("< ")
if (int(tryh5) > int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi metia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh5) < int(rand4)):
    print "Mititebuli ricxvi naklebia chafiqrebulze."
elif (int(tryh5) == int(rand4)):
    print "Gilocavt tqven gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi."
```

Comment: You mean I need to set all "If" "Elif" and "tryh" at same level?

Comment: I'm no expert at Python but his code works, so i'm guessing yes

Comment: Thank you very much mate :)

Comment: No problem! if it worked be sure to mark this as answered

Comment: Sure I will the thing is that my whole script is 300 lines so now I'm working to make them all on same level :) Uh yes, and one more thing, I also use in my script random.randint(1,250) do I need to set it on same level as if elif and tryh too? :)

Comment: Can I please send you whole script and can you fix it ? :( I'm really sorry if I'm being annoying :(

Comment: Oh no its fine but try some more. If you want to get better at programming, you have to learn how to handle errors. If all else fails yeah you can send it to me

Comment: Well yeah, I tried to do thing you told me but it still throws error but now on  "print "Gamoicanit chafiqrebuli ricxvi [1,250]"... I don't really know what to do... So can I please send it to you?.. If no, Its ok just tell me.

Comment: post it on pastebin and send me the link

Comment: Oh bro thank you very much... Here it is : http://pastebin.com/RDFz6xwF

Comment: Omg dude you made my day <3 Thank you so much!